# Engineering Drawing-Projection of intersection curve of two standing cones

Tags: mechanical-engineering, technical-drawing, drawings

I have this projection of two intersecting cones, and I am asked to draw the intersection curve of the two cones on the projection. What is the right way to do it? [image]

Comment: I would first imagine the shape of the intersect, then locate the points of intersection...

Comment: That is what I am struggling with- locating the points of intersection. I think that there are specific generating lines of the wider cone that intersect with specific generating lines of the narrower cone. I just can't seem to find those specific intersection points.

Comment: Start with the center lines then locate the four extremities on those lines and then continue to draw the dots...

Comment: I found two intersection points so far- on the top view and the side view- using the two intersection points in the front view(of the center lines). How do I go further with this?

Comment: You don't seem to have grasped the basic idea of why projections are useful. Suppose you take a generating line from the top of the large cone. You can draw the *same* line on all *three* projections, and each projective view will tell you *something* about how it intersects the small cone. Piece that information together and you have the point of intersection. (Actually you don't need all three views - two are enough).

Comment: I am sorry, I started learning this just recently. I did draw the the same generating line of the large cone in all three projections- but I don't know how I can see the intersecting point of this line with the smaller cone. There is a specific generating line of the smaller cone that intersects this specific generating line of the larger cone that I created- but I can't seem to find it.I can I attach what I did so far if it helps.

Comment: Determine the intersection points of your upper and lower and one of the sides.  Based on your x/y numbers, it's going to have a roundish shape.  Probably more egg shaped than an ellipse.

Comment: How do I determine them? I found only two intersection points using the front view. How can I use the other views to find more intersections?

Answer (score 2):

Have look at this and then see which intersections give you the points for the outline (this is not exact - just lines drawn on a simple graphics package...

See:

[image]