# Projection of a given view to produce another views

Tags: technical-drawing

[image: given the following views, project a third view in the direction of the arrow in first angle projections,][image: given the following views, project two other views as shown]

First as a beginner in Technical drawing, I'm required to project two other views from the given views. In the first image the original object was not given and I'm required to produce the third view. I felt there should be the original object to be able to get dimension. Unlike the second drawing where the original object was shown so it becomes a little easier. 
All I need is a correct way of approaching this kind of drawing in order to be guided accordingly.
Thanks in anticipation[image]

Comment: Have a look at : https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/28568/10902

Comment: The whole point of tech drawing is that the drawings *are* a complete definition of the original object. And if you think about it, a "3D drawing" of the object is just a projection from a different angle! So you need to learn how to visualize the 3D object directly from the drawing, *without* needing a sketch as well.