# Conversion of orthographic projection to isometric projection

Tags: mechanical-engineering, civil-engineering, cad, technical-drawing, drawings

I'm new to engineering drawing, and I am having trouble drawing isometric projection from orthographic projections.

Can someone give the steps/thought process behind this conversion?

I can upload the problem if someone needs an example of what I am trying to say.

Comment: @SolarMike My question is how to draw it from orthographic projection.. which is not the thing discussed in this question.

Comment: Perhaps this one might help you progress: https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/28568/10902