# How to draw a isometric view of the block in the picture below?

Tags: materials, homework

Can anyone give me some guidance with this question? I'm finding it a bit difficult.How is the object suppose to look like?[image]

Comment: think about this ... the short vertical line in the middle of the first diagram ... what does it represent?

Comment: This may give you a hint: https://engineering.stackexchange.com/a/28582/10902

Comment: Think which line is the dashed line and which line is the vertical and it should become obvious. Good test question though, you either know how to do it or not.

Comment: another trick ...  turn the page upside down

Comment: In the top view, how do you know where point S is?  To me it should be the tip of semi circle (quadrant) but the location of the letter S in that view does not seem to support that.  I am making my assumption based on the elevation view.