# Missing View and Isometric Projection

Tags: technical-drawing

i'm having a hard time to project the missing top view and the isometric projection. My professor did not give me any information about what angle it is (like third angle or first angle), so I'm super confused on how to draw it:(

[image]

I tried to draw it and this is the result, but I still could not visualize the diagonal line inside[image]

The white dot is the point where it appear simultaneously on both line, but how do you connect it with the bottom of the diagonal :')[image]

Is it like this? pls give me a tips on how to be good at this:') i have an exam coming up[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Engineering Drawing-Projection of intersection curve of two standing cones](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/28568/engineering-drawing-projection-of-intersection-curve-of-two-standing-cones)

Comment: Turn the triangle you have srawn and erased and flip it upside down

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a homework question we won't give you a direct answer but instead, lead you through the steps to visualise and draw the solution.

> I'm super confused on how to draw it.

Then do this:

[image]

*Figure 1.*

[image]

*Figure 2.*

Now which is the more likely projection?

Can you fill in the missing view? Edit your post to include your solution.

> third angle or first angle ...

If faced with uncertainty like this in an assignment or exam I would provide both. If pressed for time I would provide one and state my assumption regarding the projection standard.

---

Update 1

OK. Your cuboid is correct. You're just missing the diagonal.

[image]

*Figure 3. A hint.*

- Look at the red circle at the top of the diagonal. This means that the top of the diagonal must be somewhere along the red line on the isometric.
- Similarly the same point viewed on the other view (circled in green) must be somewhere on the green line.

Now what point could be on both lines simultaneously?

Can you do the same operation for the bottom of the diagonal?

Update the sketch when you've got that sorted and add it into your question (but leave the existing ones so that future readers can see the thought process).

Edit 2:

[image]

*Figure 4. The isometric view - as you had worked out.*

Comment: I already tried to draw it, but i got confuse with the diagonal line

Comment: So edit your question and show us the parts you *have* figured out. This is homework so we're not going to do it for you but will help if you show your effort.

Comment: I already find the point where it could be on both lines, but i still could not find the bottom of the diagonal

Comment: Repeat the exercise did with the top point for the bottom point. Mark the points on the elevations (maybe use blue and yellow) and draw the lines on the isometric. Where do they intersect?

Comment: hello, i already come up with an answer, is that correct? now i feel like i understand the drawing more, at first I thought that the diagonal line has to be in the same plane as in the view, but there is a cut out block (?? i don't know the word) so that the diagonal line is not actually on the same plane as in the view

Comment: You have understood correctly. (See my Update 2.) Now you need to do the missing projection.