# Missing View From Orthographic Third Angle

Tags: technical-drawing

so the drawing is missing the right side view, but i'm having a hard time to visualize how it look, especially the 90° part[image]

Comment: Have a look at: https://engineering.stackexchange.com/a/28582/10902

Comment: This appears to be homework so we won't provide you with a solution. Show your work so far and we'll give you some help. See also  https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/56644/missing-view-and-isometric-projection/56645 which has a solution in progress.

Answer (score 0):

This is not your third view, but it might help you visualize things

> [image]